# Is there enough evidence in this paper that there is a second (mechanical) layer of information in DNA?

Tags: dna

The following commentator [writes](https://www.physics.leidenuniv.nl/index.php?id=11573&news=889&type=LION&ln=EN):

> Mechanical cues
>   Since the mid 80s it has been hypothesized that there is a second layer of information on top of the genetic code: DNA’s mechanical properties. Each of our cells contains two meters of DNA molecules, so these molecules need to be wrapped up tightly to fit inside a single cell. The way in which DNA is folded, determines how the letters are read out, and therefore which proteins are actually made. In each organ, only relevant parts of the genetic information are read, based on how the DNA is folded. The theory goes that mechanical cues within the DNA structures determine how DNA prefers to fold.

My question is: **Is there enough evidence in this paper that there is a second (mechanical) layer of information in DNA?**

Comment: ...isn't your question answered in the paragraph following the one you're citing?

Comment: I was trying to work out of this paper had any credentials or not. You’re saying it does?

Comment: Ah, it isn't clear from your question that you actually want info **about this paper**. I suggest you to rephrase it to actually include what you ask in the comment. Something like "Is there enough evidence in this paper that there is a second (mechanical) layer of information in DNA?". In the meanwhile I'll check the paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SE Biology does not exist to referee scientific papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biologists already know that transcription can be regulated by winding or unwinding DNA.  (This paper might be informative:http://www.cell.com/trends/parasitology/fulltext/S1471-4922(16)30226-4)

But this is hardly the only method of gene regulation.